# Email Width not being respected in Outlook for Windows (only)

Tags: html, email, outlook

My email HTML sets widths for Tables / inside content, and it works well on Mac & Mobile; Windows Outlook, on the other hand, has the Header/Footer content at one width, and the Body Content at another (wider) width.

I've been banging my head trying to figure this out - and am at a loss.
I've searched through S.O. to see if others figured this out, but haven't had any luck there, either.

Any help would be appreciated.

Code below:

```html
<body style="padding:0; margin:0;" bgcolor="#dadada">
    <div style="display:none;font-size:1px;color:#333333;line-height:1px;max-height:0px;max-width:0px;opacity:0;overflow:hidden;"> Focus on what really matters at work and don't give your feet a second thought when wearing our most popular professional styles: flats, heels and more. </div>
    <!-- END PREVIEW TEXT -->
    <!-- header wrapper -->
    <table width="100%" bgcolor="#F9F8F8" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding:0;margin:0;border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;table-layout:fixed;">
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <table width="600" bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="width320" style="border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;color:#ffffff;font-family:gothamy, 'helvetica neue', helvetica, arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;min-width:300px !important;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table width="2" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="hide" style="border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;color:#ffffff;font-family:'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Sans', 'DejaVu Sans', 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;font-size:14px;">
                                <tr>
                                    <td height="5" valign="middle" style="color:#808080;font-family:gothamy, 'helvetica neue', helvetica, arial, sans-serif;font-size:10px;line-height:15px;" mc:edit="preheader"></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <table width="100%" align="right" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="preheader" style="border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;color:#ffffff;font-family:gothamy, 'helvetica neue', helvetica, arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;text-align:left;">
                                <!-- preheader -->
                                <tr>
                                    <td height="30" valign="middle" style="mso-line-height-rule:exactly;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;color:#808080;font-family:gothamy, 'helvetica neue', helvetica, arial, sans-serif;font-size:10px;line-height:15px;">  <b>Look forward to Spring with these hot new styles!</b>
                                        <br>   Can't see images? <a href="*|ARCHIVE|*" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:underline;color:#808080 !important;"><span style="color:#808080; text-decoration:none;">View this in your browser</span></a>.</td>
                                </tr>
                                <!-- end preheader -->
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table width="100%" bgcolor="#F9F8F8" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding:0;margin:0;border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;">
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <table bgcolor="#ffffff" width="600" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;" class="width320">
                    <tr>
                        <td height="20" width="100%" colspan="3"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <!-- spacing -->
                    <tr>
                        <td width="2" style="color:#ffffff;font-family:'Gotham A', 'Gotham B', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;" valign="middle" align="center">
                            <table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;" class="width280">
                                <!-- logo -->
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center" mc:edit="logo"><a href="http://www.vionicshoes.ca"> <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/f65fdf760c91701e37252f426/images/eee1454a-c0ce-4029-8047-8a13eb4811c3.gif" width="240" border="0" style="max-width:600px;" class="width280" alt="Vionic®"></a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <!-- end logo -->
                                <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <!-- header nav -->
                            <table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" bgcolor="#000000" style="height:50px;font-family:gothamy, 'helvetica neue', helvetica, arial, sans-serif;color:#ffffff;">
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="37" class="hide"></td>
                                    <td align="center" width="525" class="nav-block">
                                        <table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="height:25px;border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-color:#ffffff;" bgcolor="#000000" class="width320nav">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="center" style="mso-line-height-rule:exactly;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;font-family:'MrsEavesOT-Roman', 'times new roman', serif;color:#ffffff !important;padding:10px 0;" class="nav-block"><a href="https://vionicshoes.ca/collections/women" style="color:#ffffff !important;text-decoration:none;font-weight:200;font-size:17px;" class="block"><span style="color:#ffffff; text-decoration:none;">SHOP WOMEN</span></a>
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="hide"> </td>
                                                <td class="nav-block show" width="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-size:0px;line-height:0px;display:none;height:0px;width:0px;max-height:0px;max-width:0px;"></td>
                                                <td align="center" style="mso-line-height-rule:exactly;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;font-family:'MrsEavesOT-Roman', 'times new roman', serif;color:#ffffff !important;padding:10px 0;" class="nav-block"><a href="https://vionicshoes.ca/collections/men" style="color:#ffffff !important;text-decoration:none;font-weight:200;font-size:17px;" class="block"><span style="color:#ffffff; text-decoration:none;">SHOP MEN</span></a>
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="hide"> </td>
                                                <td class="hide" width="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-size:0px;line-height:0px;display:none;height:0px;width:0px;max-height:0px;max-width:0px;"></td>
                                                <td align="center" style="mso-line-height-rule:exactly;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;font-family:'MrsEavesOT-Roman', 'times new roman', serif;color:#ffffff !important;" class="hide"><a href="https://vionicshoes.ca/pages/supportive-technology" style="color:#ffffff !important;text-decoration:none;font-weight:200;font-size:17px;" class="hide"><span style="color:#ffffff; text-decoration:none;">SUPPORTIVE TECHNOLOGY</span></a>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                    <td width="37" class="hide"></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <!-- end header nav -->
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <!-- /header wrapper -->
    <!-- body wrapper -->
    <table width="100%" bgcolor="#F9F8F8" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding:0;margin:0;border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;"><!-- table-layout:fixed;
 -->        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <table width="600" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;min-width:300px !important;" bgcolor="#ffffff" class="width320">
                    <!-- full-width copy -->
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" style="min-width:300px !important;">
                            <p style="margin:25px auto 0px;padding:0;font-family:'SackersGothicStd-Medium', sans-serif;font-size:22px;line-height:140%;letter-spacing:1px;color:#000000;text-align:center;text-transform:uppercase;font-weight:500;width:95%;">Step out in subtle chic</p>
                            <p style="margin:0px auto 15px;padding:0;font-family:gothamy, 'helvetica neue', helvetica, arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-style:normal !important;line-height:150%;letter-spacing:1px;color:#000000;text-align:center;width:76%;">Available in bright colours and warm neutrals, our new sandals go everywhere you do, from sunrise to sunset.</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <!-- end full-width copy -->
                    <!-- full-width cta -->
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" style="min-width:300px !important;">
                            <table class="width320nav" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center" style="color:#ffffff;padding:15px 0 0;text-align:center;" mc:edit="herbutton">
                                        <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="max-width:200px;min-width:200px;" width="200">
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td align="center" style="max-width:300px;display:block !important;background-color:#ffffff;border:1px solid #000000;padding:10px;font-family:'SackersGothicStd-Medium', sans-serif;font-size:12px;font-weight:500;line-height:105%;letter-spacing:1px;text-align:center;"><a href="https://vionicshoes.ca/collections/womens-sandals" style="color:#000000;text-decoration:none;padding:10px;">SHOP SANDALS</a>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <!-- end button -->
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <!-- three-column content -->
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" style="min-width:300px !important;">
                            <table class="width320" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="32%">
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center">
                                        <img border="0" class="width320" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/df9c3a35085c40dd1033b83bf/images/4f936c5d-aec4-407b-bc0e-a6b668abc01f.jpg" style="max-width: 196px; margin: auto; padding: 0" width="196" alt="Coming Soon: Lorne">
                                        
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <table class="width320" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="32%">
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center">
                                        <a href="https://vionicshoes.ca/products/kirrasandal"><img border="0" class="width320" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/df9c3a35085c40dd1033b83bf/images/95cd618b-6e44-4879-9f3b-fad394664080.jpg" style="max-width: 196px; margin: auto; padding: 0" width="196" alt="Kirra"></a>
                                        <!--                  <p style="margin:10px auto;padding:0;font-family:'MrsEavesOT-Italic', 'times new roman', serif;font-size:12px;line-height:120%;letter-spacing:1px;color:#000000;text-align:center;"><a href="https://vionicshoes.ca/products/kirrasandal" style="font-size:12px;color:#ff4621;text-decoration:none;"><span style="font-size: 12px; color: #ff4621; text-decoration:none">
              <i>NEW! <span style="color: #000">Kirra</span>
              </i></span></a>
            </p>-->
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <table class="width320" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="32%">
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center">
                                        <a href="https://vionicshoes.ca/collections/womens-sandals/products/catalinasandal"><img border="0" class="width320" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/df9c3a35085c40dd1033b83bf/images/ecc64309-c40e-407d-af58-62b95e975d2b.jpg" style="max-width: 196px; margin: auto; padding: 0" width="196" alt="Catalina"></a>
                                        
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <!-- end three-column content -->
                    <!--
    <tr>
      <td height="10" colspan="2">
      </td>
    </tr>
    -->
                    <!-- end spacer -->
                    <!--  Full width image-->
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" style="min-width:300px !important;">
                            <table class="width320" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="96%">
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center"><a href="https://vionicshoes.ca/products/bellaiisandal"><img border="0" class="width320" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/df9c3a35085c40dd1033b83bf/images/0f605e1b-bdfc-43fb-9736-c9774b41cc78.jpg" style="max-width: 96%; width: 588px; margin: auto; padding: 0" alt="Bella"></a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <!-- three-column content -->
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" style="min-width:300px !important;">
                            <table class="width320" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="32%">
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center"><a href="https://vionicshoes.ca/products/bellaiisandal"><img border="0" class="width320" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/df9c3a35085c40dd1033b83bf/images/218d016f-850b-4484-be39-812c898b9de2.jpg" style="max-width: 196px; margin: auto; padding: 0" width="196" alt="Bella"></a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <table class="width320" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="32%">
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center"><a href="https://vionicshoes.ca/products/bellaiisandal"><img border="0" class="width320" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/df9c3a35085c40dd1033b83bf/images/a9f43d2c-aaeb-4128-906c-22c2ec0e7f13.jpg" style="max-width: 196px; margin: auto; padding: 0" width="196" alt="Bella"></a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <table class="width320" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="32%">
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center"><a href="https://vionicshoes.ca/products/bellaiisandal"><img border="0" class="width320" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/df9c3a35085c40dd1033b83bf/images/4cf6b46c-208b-4497-bca1-44c3c6418808.jpg" style="max-width: 196px; margin: auto; padding: 0" width="196" alt="Bella"></a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <!-- end three-column content -->
                    <!-- three-column content -->
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" style="min-width:300px !important;">
                            <table class="width320" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="32%">
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center"><a href="https://vionicshoes.ca/products/midiperf"><img border="0" class="width320" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/df9c3a35085c40dd1033b83bf/images/2d57acb7-f623-4f49-90ab-0250e704a248.jpg" style="max-width: 196px; margin: auto; padding: 0" width="196" alt="Midi Perf"></a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <table class="width320" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="32%">
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center"><a href="https://vionicshoes.ca/products/joey"><img border="0" class="width320" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/df9c3a35085c40dd1033b83bf/images/b885ec53-341d-4018-8e73-f097c3ec682a.jpg" style="max-width: 196px; margin: auto; padding: 0" width="195" alt="Joey"></a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <table class="width320" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="32%">
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center"><a href="https://vionicshoes.ca/products/ediesneaker"><img border="0" class="width320" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/df9c3a35085c40dd1033b83bf/images/7bc1b19f-f704-458a-8869-9c20b5b2f4dd.jpg" style="max-width: 196px; margin: auto; padding: 0" width="196" alt="Edie"></a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <!-- end three-column content -->
                    <!--  Full width image-->
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" style="min-width:300px !important;">
                            <table class="width320" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="96%">
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center"><a href="https://vionicshoes.ca/products/bellaiisandal"><img border="0" class="width320" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/df9c3a35085c40dd1033b83bf/images/9a07d8b5-7e12-4540-b882-007774b799bd.jpg" style="max-width: 96%; width: 588px; margin: auto; padding: 0" alt="Bella"></a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <!--          <td height="30" colspan="2">
</td>-->
                    <!-- end spacer -->
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <!-- /body wrapper -->
    <!-- footer wrapper -->
    <table width="100%" bgcolor="#F9F8F8" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding:0;margin:0;border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;table-layout:fixed;">
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <table width="600" bgcolor="#373131" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;text-align:center;" class="width320">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" class="width320">
                            <table width="600" bgcolor="#000000" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;color:#444444;font-family:gothamy, 'helvetica neue', helvetica, arial, sans-serif;font-size:10px;text-align:center;" class="width320">
                                <tr>
                                    <td height="20" width="100%"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <!-- spacing -->
                                <!-- footer nav 1 -->
                                <tr align="center">
                                    <td>
                                        <table align="center" width="320" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="color:#ffffff;font-family:gothamy, 'helvetica neue', helvetica, arial, sans-serif;font-size:12px;">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="center"><span class="block"><a href="https://vionicshoes.ca/pages/30-day-guarantee" style="color:#ffffff !important;text-decoration:none;font-weight:500;letter-spacing:1px;"><span style="color:#ffffff; text-decoration:none;">30-DAY WEAR TEST</span></a> | <a href="https://vionicshoes.ca/pages/find-a-store" style="color:#ffffff !important;text-decoration:none;font-weight:500;letter-spacing:1px;"><span style="color:#ffffff; text-decoration:none;">FIND A STORE</span></a></span>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <!-- end footer nav 1 -->
                                <tr>
                                    <td height="5" width="100%"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <!-- spacing -->
                                <!-- footer nav 2 -->
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="100%">
                                        <table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;" class="width320nav">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="center" style="color:#ffffff;font-family:gothamy, 'helvetica neue', helvetica, arial, sans-serif;font-size:10px;text-align:center;"><span class="block"><a href="https://vionicshoes.ca/pages/faqs" style="color:#ffffff !important;text-decoration:none;"><span style="color:#ffffff; text-decoration:none;">FAQ</span></a> | <a href="https://vionicshoes.ca/pages/contact-us" style="color:#ffffff !important;text-decoration:none;"><span style="color:#ffffff; text-decoration:none;">CONTACT US</span></a> | <a href="*|UNSUB|*" style="color:#ffffff !important;text-decoration:none;"><span style="color:#ffffff; text-decoration:none;">UNSUBSCRIBE</span></a></span>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <!-- end footer nav 2 -->
                                <!-- social -->
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="100%" class="width320">
                                        <div align="center" mc:edit="socialicons" style="margin:10px auto;padding:0;">
                                            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/VionicShoesCanada" style="text-decoration:none;"><img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/f65fdf760c91701e37252f426/images/4f0797d7-defb-47de-a41d-7f5da63c3274.png" width="20" border="0" title="Facebook" alt="4f0797d7-defb-47de-a41d-7f5da63c3274.png"></a> <a href="https://www.instagram.com/vioniccanada/" style="text-decoration:none;"><img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/f65fdf760c91701e37252f426/images/b94436f2-347d-4781-bcfa-7f51c0e7460f.png" width="20" border="0" title="Instagram" alt="b94436f2-347d-4781-bcfa-7f51c0e7460f.png"></a><a href="https://twitter.com/VionicCanada" style="text-decoration:none;"> <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/f65fdf760c91701e37252f426/images/4d973ac0-a4a5-42a4-963d-7deddc0b127f.png" width="20" border="0" title="Twitter" alt="4d973ac0-a4a5-42a4-963d-7deddc0b127f.png"></a>  <a href="http://www.youtube.com/vionicshoes" style="text-decoration:none;"><img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/f65fdf760c91701e37252f426/images/1b8863d9-8cce-46f3-8fce-aeb3281581b6.png" width="20" border="0" title="Youtube" alt="1b8863d9-8cce-46f3-8fce-aeb3281581b6.png"></a>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <!-- end social -->
                                <tr>
                                    <td height="10" width="100%"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <!-- spacing -->
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <table width="600" bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;color:#444444;font-family:gothamy, 'helvetica neue', helvetica, arial, sans-serif;font-size:10px;text-align:center;" class="width320">
                    <!-- company info -->
                    <tr align="center">
                        <td width="600" align="center">
                            <br><span style="color:#000000">© *|CURRENT_YEAR|* *|LIST:COMPANY|*. All rights reserved.</span>
                            <br><a href="https://www.vionicshoes.ca" style="text-decoration:none !important;border:none;color:#000000 !important;"><span style="color:#000000; text-decoration:none;">*|HTML:LIST_ADDRESS_HTML|*</span></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <!-- end company info -->
                    <tr>
                        <td height="20" bgcolor="#ffffff"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <!--spacer -->
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <!-- /footer wrapper -->
    <!-- gmail ios fix -->
    <div style="display:none !important;white-space:nowrap;font:15px courier;color:#ffffff;"> - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix a few things but you will have to work on it more. The easy fixes are:

- The image with lady and 30 day wear test didnt have a width on the img tag. Outlook doesnt like retina images so always use image widths for those that will extend beyond your template width.

Lady image fix:

```html
<table class="width320" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="96%">
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center"><a href="https://vionicshoes.ca/products/bellaiisandal"><img border="0" class="width320" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/df9c3a35085c40dd1033b83bf/images/0f605e1b-bdfc-43fb-9736-c9774b41cc78.jpg" style="max-width: 96%; width: 588px; margin: auto; padding: 0; display:block;" alt="Bella" width="588"></a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
```

Bottom image fixed:

```html
<table class="width320" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="96%">
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center"><a href="https://vionicshoes.ca/products/bellaiisandal"><img border="0" class="width320" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/df9c3a35085c40dd1033b83bf/images/9a07d8b5-7e12-4540-b882-007774b799bd.jpg" style="max-width: 96%; width: 588px; margin: auto; padding: 0; display:block;" alt="Bella" width="588"></a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
```

Things to note:

- You are missing display blocks on images
- Once all above fixes are placed in there are white lines between images, you will need to see the images are right sizes and resized the right way to eliminate the annoying lines.

Full fixed code of email can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/syfer/6f7t4h1d/).

Hope this is the answer you were after.